# Dynamically populating jQueryMobile listview from google news feed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Please could someone help me understand how I'd reference the following js code in jquerymobile. The codedynamically populates jQueryMobile listview from google news feed. But I'm unsure how I call it into my html file, or reference it

https://gist.github.com/poonkave/5405318

I presume I need to start with this in jquery mobile, is it the "feedContent" ID that I need to reference in the below code to populate the list?

```
<!-- Home -->
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="true">
            <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading">
                Divider
            </li>
            <li data-theme="c">
                <a href="#" data-transition="slide">
                    Button
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else is looking for a jquery mobile twitter feed solution, this is what I found and used. Just what I needed.

http://www.jasonmayes.com/projects/twitterApi/